Unknown password for rsync
I always used to send files to other ubuntu machines via rsync with no problems. But now the computer asks for the remote computer's password every time I try to use rsync. I use the login computer's password but keeps on telling me "Permission denied, please try again". How can I get this program working? What's the password it is asking for?

If my answer solves your requirements, please consider accepting the answer. This will help in future searches on this problem.

The computer does not have a password. rysnc is asking for the password for the account on the remote host that is being used. Depending on your rsync command line, this might be the same username as on your local machine. You can also set up ssh keys to connect without asking for a password.
